# Display route.steps (swift )

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am having some problem when it comes to display the steps from MKDirections route into a UILabel. I tried get each index from the steps array using the **for in loop**, it only show the **Arrive at destination** which means that all the instructions within the loop went by so fast, therefore i am seeing the last index in the array . Can someone help me please ...

Answer (score 0):

it shows "Arrive at destination" because you are cycling the whole array and the label gets only the object at the end, you are basically overwriting it over and over until the for cycle arrives to its final element

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing only the last value from the array in the UILabel, though it is actually displaying all the values very, very quickly. If you just want to see each of the values in the UILabel, you could either use UITimeInterval to change the value every few seconds, or add a UIButton that would handle updating of the text on the UILabel.

Comment: How Should I use the a timer if i don't know when the user will get to new checkpoint ..

Comment: So how about update the UILabel when the users get to the new checkpoint? Are you tracking when users get to the checkpoint?